# afterSave() gives error trying to get property of non-object in octoberCMS

Tags: octobercms

i am trying to get path of uploaded file using fileupload widget and then copying that file in custom folder but when creating new record it gives error **trying to get property 'path' of non-object** when afterSave() calls.

**MODEL:**

```
 public $attachOne = [
        'file' => ['System\Models\File']
    ];

    public function afterSave()
    {
        $path = $this->file->path;
        log::info($path);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this afterSave method in your model and it will not show the error you are having.

```
public function afterSave()
{
    $sessionKey = post('_session_key');
    $file = $this->file()->withDeferred($sessionKey)->first();
    if($file){
        log::info($file->getPath());
    }
}
```

the reason is \System\Models\File is available with deferred after master model is commited its changes.

Let me know if you need more help into that.

Comment: thanks, but m using fileuploader named file and why i get error call to member function getPath() on null

Comment: did you tried my solution also??? and did you made this file required ???

Comment: yes i tried and it gives error call to member function getPath() on null and no i didn't it required. Is getPath() use some kind of library

Comment: can you update your question with fields.yaml file ??

Comment: thanks it working i just make it required. Thankyou So much