# OctoberCMS partial not updating

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, octobercms

I have an issue returning  a partial update from ajax call

```
        $.request('onClientChange', {
            data: {thisClient:thisClient}, 
            update: {sessionlist: '#sessionlist'},
            success: function() {
            //alert(' Made it');
            }
        });
```

The handler onClientChange looks like this

```
function onClientChange(){
$currentClient  =  post('thisClient');
$this['currentClient']  =  $currentClient;
 $sessionSql  =  "SELECT * FROM hdl_sessions where ClientID  =  $currentClient";
 $sessionDataset  =  $this->fetchData($sessionSql);
 $this['sessionDataset']  =  $sessionDataset;
```

}

The data returns directly to $sessionDataset and looking at the network tab in Chrome, I can see the partial data (an updated table structure) returning via the XHR log.  The HTML table data renders fine statically when pasted into a blank page. It doesn't appear in the div marked by the ID

```
                <div id = "sessionlist" class = "table-responsive">
                    {% partial "sessionlist"  %}
                </div>
```

Any help gratefully received

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use complete function instead of success function in javascript API

```
$.request('onClientChange', {
    data: {thisClient:thisClient}, 
    update: {sessionlist: '#sessionlist'},
    complete: function() {
    //alert(' Made it');
    }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant Zakir, really appreciate the help. Works perfectly now :-)  Hope the docs will get updated soon

Comment: Wow nice to know that @Prema !!!  can you mark the answer to right checked please ???

Comment: @Prema please see this answer and see how they ticked on right sign

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924175/aftersave-gives-error-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-octobercms/51924348#51924348

Comment: Hope we're done. Please don't forget our appreciation :-)